# Метод Array.prototype.forEach() обходит не весь массив

Tags: javascript

Метод `Array.prototype.forEach()` обходит не весь массив...
Выводит он это:

```
0 Руслан
1 Нат
2 Алексей
3 Сергей
4 Дмитрий
5 Владислав
6 Михаил
1337 Arthas
```

А ожидал это:

```
0 Руслан
1 Нат
2 Алексей
3 Сергей
4 Дмитрий
5 Владислав
6 Михаил
app ent
1337 Arthas
```

ИЛИ

```
0 Руслан
1 Нат
2 Алексей
3 Сергей
4 Дмитрий
5 Владислав
6 Михаил
1337 Arthas
app ent
```

```js
var arr = ['Руслан', 'Нат', 'Алексей', 'Сергей', 'Дмитрий', 'Владислав', 'Михаил'];
arr['app'] = 'ent';
arr[1337] = 'Arthas';

arr.forEach(function(it, ind, arrA) {
 console.log(ind + ' ' + it);
});
```

Почему он пропускает `arr['app'] = 'ent';`?

Comment: Потому что это свойство *не элемент* массива. Под каким численным индексом Вы бы ожидали его увидеть?

Comment: @Igor, А строковый не подойдет? или индексы могут быть только числовые?

Comment: @Руслан, не подойдет для чего?

Comment: можно обойти через `for...in`, а если это объект, то можно проверить через `.hasOwnProperty(key)`